# Removing duplicate values between two dataframes in R, based on certain criteria to show only unique values

Tags: r, arrays, dataframe, compare

so I am stumped with this. I have two dataframes that I am importing into R from Excel, df1 & df2. They are very similar in nature, but df2 has some incorrect values that I need to identify. To add clarity, my desired output are the values that are either incorrect, missing, or added to df2 as opposed to df1.

There are 4 variables in this set, 'Doc #' 'Amount' 'Account' 'Df?'

'Doc #' is a unique value for each 'account', so there could be the same doc # in different accounts, but I would consider them independent of each other. 'Df?' is just an identifier I added to distinguish which df the specific observation is coming from.

Df1:

```
> dput(df1)
structure(list(Doc = c(1234L, 1234L, 1234L, 5678L, 5678L), Amt = c(500L, 
600L, 700L, 250L, 100L), Act = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B"), DF = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L
))

> df1
   Doc Amt Act DF
1 1234 500   A  1
2 1234 600   A  1
3 1234 700   A  1
4 5678 250   A  1
5 5678 100   B  1
```

df2:

```
> dput(df2)
structure(list(Doc = c(1234L, 1234L, 1234L, 5678L), Amt = c(500L, 
600L, 650L, 250L), Act = c("A", "A", "A", "A"), DF = c(2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

> df2
   Doc Amt Act DF
1 1234 500   A  2
2 1234 600   A  2
3 1234 650   A  2
4 5678 250   A  2
```

To help with visualization, I would combine the two datasets to get this, let's call this df.

```
> df
   Doc Amt Act DF
1 1234 500   A  1
2 1234 600   A  1
3 1234 700   A  1
4 5678 250   A  1
5 5678 100   B  1
6 1234 500   A  2
7 1234 600   A  2
8 1234 650   A  2
9 5678 250   A  2
```

2 things to take away from this.

1. Looking at this combined dataset, we can see on lines 3 & 6 that
   'Doc #: 1234' has an 'Amount' value of '700' in the df1 and '650' in
   the df2.
2. In line 5, we see 'Doc #: 5678' with a value of 100 in 'Account: B'; however, this entry is only on df1 and not included in df2, so I want to capture this value.

Finally I would want my final output to look like this

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. So far I have tried the `compare_df` function, but the results aren't exactly the easiest to interpret as this is a rather large dataset.

Comment: Hi Max, could you edit the question so it shows a minimal reproducible example? Ensure to include what your current output is and what you desire to get. To help, please review this excellent post on [how to ask a good question.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not difficult

```
#sample data

> df
   Doc Amt Act DF
1 1234 500   A  1
2 1234 600   A  1
3 1234 700   A  1
4 5678 250   A  1
5 5678 100   B  1
6 1234 500   A  2
7 1234 600   A  2
8 1234 650   A  2
9 5678 250   A  2
```

proceed like this

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(Doc, Amt, Act) %>% filter(n() == 1)

# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   Doc, Amt, Act [3]
    Doc   Amt Act      DF
  <int> <int> <chr> <int>
1  1234   700 A         1
2  5678   100 B         1
3  1234   650 A         2
```

I think that serves the purpose

Comment: Hi, yes this worked perfectly. Thank you!